# Ruby/RoR - Count occurrence of an element in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'v a hash

`{1=>true, 7=>false, 6=>true, 4=>false}`

or an array like

`[1, true], [7, false], [6, true], [4, false]]`

or

`[true, false, true, false]`.

How can I find the number of `true`s in the array?

Comment: As of Ruby 2.7 you can use Enumerable#tally. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488644/ruby-ror-count-occurrence-of-an-element-in-an-array/56493767#answer-5649376756493767).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In order to count the elements, you obviously have to iterate over the collection. Since iterating over a `Hash` yields two-element `Array`s, the first two are actually exactly the same:

```
{ 1 => true, 7 => false, 6 => true, 4 => false }.count(&:last)
[[1, true], [7, false], [6, true], [4, false]].count(&:last)
```

For the simple `Array` case, you could do something like this:

```
[true, false, true, false].count(true)
```

This `Array` is of course also the same as the `Hash#values` from your `Hash` above, so you could use the same method on that:

```
{ 1 => true, 7 => false, 6 => true, 4 => false }.values.count(true)
```

If you don't know which one of three you will get, you could use something like this:

```
{ 1 => true, 7 => false, 6 => true, 4 => false }.flatten.count(true)
[[1, true], [7, false], [6, true], [4, false]].flatten.count(true)
[true, false, true, false].flatten.count(true)
```

Answer (score 7):

With [Enumerable#count](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/count):

```
hash.values.count(true)
array_of_pairs.map { |k, v| v }.count(true)
plain_array.count(true)
```

More verbose, but does not create intermediate arrays:

```
hash_or_array_of_pairs.inject(0) { |acc, (k, v)| acc + (v == true ? 1 : 0) }
```

Answer (score 5):

**Ruby 2.7+**

Ruby 2.7 is introducing `Enumerable#tally` (and possibly `tally_by`) for this exact purpose. There's a good summary [here](https://speakerdeck.com/k_tsj/pattern-matching-new-feature-in-ruby-2-dot-7).

There's a discussion about whether the final implementation will use `tally` or `tally_by` when providing a block, as here.

In this use case:

```
# or hash.tally_by if that's the accepted method for block form
hash.tally { |k, v| v }
# => { true => 2, false => 2 }
```

Docs on the features being released are [here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/05/30/ruby-2-7-0-preview1-released/).

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 4):

Simpler:

```
hash.values.count(true)

array.flatten.count(true)
```

This works with all the above cases.

Comment: yeah, but in the case of the array with pairs, array.flatten.count(true) is conceptually weird, as it's taking in account also the keys (first item in pair). I know a true should never be found there, but still...

Comment: Well, if one was concerned about the keys possibly containing a true, as unlikely as it is, you could do this: `Hash[array].values.count(true)`

Answer (score 2):

For hashes:

```
{ :a => true, :b => true, :c => false }.select{ |k,v| v }.length
 => 2
```

For arrays:

```
[true, false, false, true, true].select{ |o| o }.length
 => 3
```

Another way (testing with a negation):

```
[true, false, false, true, true].reject{ |o| o != true }.length
 => 3
```

Answer (score 1):

One way (your hash would need `.to_a` called on it first for this to work on it):

```
[[1, true], [7, false], [6, true], [4, false]].flatten.select{|s| s == true }.size
```

Comment: note that `s == true` could be simplified to `s`

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to provide a more general answer: count the amount of each element. I'm still using `2.6.6`, so somebody else also has no `2.7.x`.
**Preparation**:

```
values_of_hash = {1=>true, 7=>false, 6=>true, 4=>false}.values # also works with the `.map` command from the line below
values_of_array_of_pairs = [[1, true], [7, false], [6, true], [4, false]].map { |k, v| v } # or the `.inject` command from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488905/4575793
values_of_2d = [[1, true], [7, false], [6, true], [4, false]].map(&:last) # similar idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4490032/4575793
values_of_2d = {1=>true, 7=>false, 6=>true, 4=>false}.map(&:last) # both a hash and an array of pairs hold the second value in `.last`
values_of_array = [true, false, true, false]
```

Now you can just use

```
def my_tally(values)
  Set.new(values).map {|unique_value| [unique_value, values.count(unique_value)]}
end
# replace `_xy` with anything of the above like e.g. `_array`
my_tally values_of_xy
# => [[true, 2], [false, 2]]
```

That also works for arbitrary data. Maybe you want to analyse this:

```
values_of_xy = {1=>:banana, 2=>:cherry, 3=>:apple, 4=>:cherry, 5=>:banana, 6=>:cherry}.values
my_tally values_of_xy
# => [[:banana, 2], [:cherry, 3], [:apple, 1]]
```

---

**[For Ruby 2.7+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56493767/4575793), you should obviously use [tally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488644/ruby-ror-count-occurrence-of-an-element-in-an-array/56493767#answer-5649376756493767).**

Answer (score 0):

Hash:

`my_hash.values.select(&:present?).size`

2D array:

`my_2d_array.map(&:last).select(&:present?).size`

or

`my_2d_array.select { |_first, last| last.present? }.size`

1D array:

`array.select(&:present?).size`